# JSON.stringify - downcasting an object

Tags: json, object, stringify, downcast

Is there a way to tell the stringify method to convert an object to a primitive datatype?

```
class Bar {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'bar';
    }
}

const obj = {foo: new Bar};

JSON.stringify(obj);

// output:        '{foo: {name: 'bar'}}'
// wanted output: '{foo:'bar'}'
```

I've tried overriding toSting and valueOf methods but with no results

```
Bar.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.name;
}

Bar.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return this.name;
}
```

Comment: add a [`toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#tojson_behavior) to your class, that returns "bar".

Answer (score 2):

Add **toJSON** prototype method in Bar class.

```
Bar.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    return this.name;
}
```